# Is there a way to upload videos to youtube from our Website?

Tags: php, video, upload, youtube

I am developing a website, where I am allowing users to upload videos, but if the members numbers keep on increasing and they keep on uploading more videos it will be expensive for me. So I want to upload the movies to youtube instead, is this possible?

By viewing some other posts here, I am thinking it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need **[Youtube API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html)** to upload the videos with PHP.

There are some ready scripts you can use to upload to youtube, the one that deserves mention here is:

**[PHPTube](http://kamleitner.com/code/phptube-youtube-api-f-video-upload-download/)**

**More Resources**

**[Use the YouTube API with PHP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-youtubeapi/)**
**[YouTube Uploader](http://llynix.com/code/php/youtube-uploader/)**

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sarfraz's links you also have the [Services_YouTube PEAR package](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.webservices.services-youtube.example.php) and the [Zend_Gdata_YouTube class](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.youtube.html). They are both very well documented.